# Accessing the Superpowered beatgrid if not using Superpowered player

Tags: superpowered

I'm using [Superpowered Offline analyzer](http://superpowered.com/docs/class_superpowered_offline_analyzer.html) to analyse audio, but am using my own player to play it.
I'd like to access the beatgrid information - which I had assumed was an output of the analyzer's getResults function, but that function seems to just take the start point of the beatgrid as an input.

I can see that beatgrid functionality is available in the [Superpowered Advance Audio Player](http://superpowered.com/docs/class_superpowered_advanced_audio_player.html) - but is there a way to access it without using a Superpowered player?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The offline analyser returns with a fixed beat-grid for modern music with constant tempo. It returns with the position of the first beat. The position of the remaining beats can be calculated from the bpm value.

Comment: Ah - fantastic - thanks Gabor. Might be worth editing your response to have 'bpm' instead of 'bam' for future readers :> What threw me was the word 'should' from the doco 'The position where the beatgrid **should** start' to me that reads like it's an input  - I should have just tried it out. Maybe that could read 'The position where the analyzer has detected the first beat. The position of the remaining beats can be calculated from the BPM value'

Comment: Gabor - maybe not the right place for this - but a couple of feature requests.. Firstly with the beatgrid - it's assuming a constant pulse through the track (if I've understood your answer) - some tracks just aren't like that. Also some media I deal with is a mixture of spoken words and musical examples. Might be nice to have access to an array of beatgrid info returned by analyze.  Also time signature detection would be awesome. THese are quibbles though - Superpowered is awesome!